# CSS: Center a parent element while leaving the sub-elements float left and aligned left

Tags: css, centering

On my frontpage, I would like to CENTER the directory view (CONTENT AREA with headline 'Golfverzeichnis'): [LINK](http://www.golfanatics.de/J3/)

Name of the CSS-Element to be centered: jrDirView

Problem-Description: the images and left-aligned links underneath them should remain unchanged, but the whole directory view area, which is right now aligned left, should be centered, so the white space left and right is equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the fallowing into your CSS jrDirView class

```
.jrDirView{
   margin: 0 auto;
   width:1000px;
}
```

you can experiment with the width until you find the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the page, the content area is already centered.

You can prove this by putting a lot of tags under one of the images that shows up in the right most column.

The problem is that your content is not centered, so to the user, it appears that the the page is off center.

You can tweak the problem by setting the left margin of jrDirView arbitrarily to force the content to appear to be centered, but it won't be a very robust solution.

A better solution might be to force the text area to be the same width (approximately) as the known width of the image and then setting a left and right padding on jrListingThumbnail and jrContentDiv

Comment: I agree. The page is already centered. It's better to decrease the width for ".jrDirview ul li.jrCatLevel1" and add "margin-right" property.